# PHP W3 Validator API, Is this good?

Tags: php, api, validation

I was trying to find a way to see if my site's code was valid or not but I continuously going over to [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org) so I decided to make an "API" however it really isn't!

I just wanted to know if anybody can find a better solution to the one I have made.
This is what I currently use, with the usage of ?uri=http://www.mydomain.com :

```
<?php
if(!$_GET['uri']) {
echo "No URI!";
}
else {
 $CheckURI = "http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=".$_GET['uri'];
 $URL = file_get_contents($CheckURI);
 $Start = strpos($URL, "<title>") + 7;
 $End = strpos($URL, "</title>");
 $Title = substr($URL, $Start, $End-$Start);
 if(preg_match('[Invalid]',$Title)) {
     //Code is INVALID
     echo "<a href='$CheckURI' title='This is not good!' target='_BLANK'>INVALID Source</a>";
 }
 elseif(preg_match('[Valid]',$Title)) {
     //Code is VALID
     echo "<a href='$CheckURI' title='Check It Yourself!' target='_BLANK'>Valid Source</a>";
 }
 else {
    //It Went WRONG
    echo "";
 }
}
```

Comment: the only thing you read from the results page is valid/invalid? What do you do with the results? How do you send the pages to the validator? And by that I mean which headers and code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think W3C had your use case in mind when they made the validator. Why not [run your own](http://validator.w3.org/docs/devel.html)? The script you made is going to be very slow because it is relaying all requests. Also, your script won't run cleanly on E_STRICT. Also, your script doesn't encode URI parameters. Also, you are unnecessarily using regexes. Also, you are not HTML encoding your URI.